# Granting privileges to a new user in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've given all the privileges to a new user to access a MySQL database using the following query

```
 grant all privileges on database.* to root@example.com identified by 'password';
```

followed by

```
 flush privileges;
```

After this i see a new row is added to mysql.user but with 'N' in all the columns (like Select_priv = N, Insert_priv=N and so on).

Does N means that the user is not granted with all the privileges?  Is this the way to grant permissions for a user? This is the first time i'm doing this. Need some help

Thanks.

Comment: Wrong table - you only granted on a specific database, try the `db` table. You also do not need to flush as you did not edit the tables directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong table, `mysql.user` defines global privileges, so if you did something like:

```
grant all privileges on *.* to root@example.com identified by 'password';
```

Then the user would appear there.

The table you want to look at is `mysql.db` which defines database specific privileges.

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't know this. So, what exactly is the difference between between the two tables mysql.user and mysql.db?

Comment: As I said, `mysql.user` is privileges on _any database_ and `mysql.db` is privileges _by database_.